# How do I remove HTML of Array using dropdown list options(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and button which invokes function that pushes the value from text box to the HTML of array. I want to remove the element that I select from the collection of options elements in dropdown list, from HTML of array. Below is the code that I figured out (does not work perfectly).

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById('element').value;
  fruits.push(element);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}

function Remove(val) {
  var x = val.options[val.selectedIndex].text;
  var index = fruits.indexOf(x);
  fruits.splice(index, 1);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="text" id="element" name="element">

<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="Remove(this)">
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Mango</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: the question is not clear to me

Comment: What is `x.selectedIndex` in Remove function ?

Comment: That was incorrect, I edited the code. It's still  not working.

Comment: I want the remove the elements that I added to the html of array entered in text box using push method (invoked on submit button). I want to select the option from dropdown list which I want to be removed from the html.I don't know how to explain it any better.

Comment: Should the elements be added back once removed from the HTML and value from array?

Comment: Yes, they can be added back once removed. Any text entered in text box and submitted using button will be added to the HTML. This can be removed by selecting the option from dropdown list and can be added back again by submitting in text box.

Comment: Sorry, If I am not clear. I don't have good command of English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

To add options dynamiclly. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) to see how options are working.

`var fSelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
fSelect.options[fSelect.options.length] = new Option(element, element);`

To remove options just use `remove` function, pass the index you want to remove

`var fSelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
fSelect.remove(index);`

```js
var fruits=["Banana","Orange","Apple","Mango"];
  
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
function myFunction()
{
  var element = document.getElementById('element').value;
  fruits.push(element);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
  
  //add a new option to select 
  var fSelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
 fSelect.options[fSelect.options.length] = new Option(element, element);
 
}

function Remove(val)
{
  var x = val.options[val.selectedIndex].text;
  var  index = fruits.indexOf(x);
  if(index>=0){
    fruits.splice(index, 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
    
    //remove element from select
    var fSelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    fSelect.remove(index);
  }  
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="text" id="element" name="element">

<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">

<form>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="Remove(this)">
<option>Banana</option>
<option>Orange</option>
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Mango</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="text" id="element" name="element">

<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="Remove()" size="8">
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Mango</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>

<script>
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction(val) {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  fruits.push(document.getElementById("element").value);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = fruits[fruits.length-1];
  x.add(option);
}

function Remove() {
  var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  for (var i=0; i<e.length; i++){
    if (e.options[i].value == strUser )
       e.remove(i);
    }
    var index = fruits.indexOf(strUser)
    fruits.splice(index, 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!! But It is only removing the options from dropdown list and not the HTML.